# Definite integral of $e^{-by^2}/(y^2-c^2)$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

How to get the definite integral like this?

$$\int^a_0 \frac{\exp(-by^2)}{y^2-c^2}dy$$ where $a,b,c$ are parameters and $a>c$.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\tt\large\mbox{Let's assume}\ \verts{c} > a > 0$:

$\ds{I \equiv \int^{a}_{0}{\expo{-by^{2}} \over y^{2} - c^{2}}\,\dd y
     =
     {1 \over \verts{c}}\int^{a/\verts{c}}_{0}
     {\expo{-bc^{2}y^{2}} \over y^{2} - 1}\,\dd y
      =
     {1 \over \verts{c}}\,{\cal F}\pars{bc^{2},{a \over \verts{c}}}}$

where
$\ds{{\cal F}\pars{\mu,\nu}
     \equiv
     \int_{0}^{\nu}{\expo{-\mu x^{2}} \over x^{2} - 1}\,\dd x}$

> \begin{align}
> &\partiald{{\cal F}\pars{\mu,\nu}}{\mu}
> =
> \int_{0}^{\nu}{\expo{-\mu x^{2}}\pars{-x^{2}} \over x^{2} - 1}\,\dd x
> =
> -\int_{0}^{\nu}\expo{-\mu x^{2}}\,\dd x
> -
> \int_{0}^{\nu}{\expo{-\mu x^{2}} \over x^{2} - 1}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=
> -\,{1 \over 2}\root{\pi \over \mu}\,{2 \over \root{\pi}}
> \int_{0}^{\nu\root{\mu}}\expo{x^{2}}\,\dd x - {\cal F}\pars{\mu,\nu}
> =
> -\,{1 \over 2}\root{\pi \over \mu}\,{\rm erf}\pars{\nu\root{\mu}}
> - {\cal F}\pars{\mu,\nu}
> \\[3mm]&
> \pars{\partiald{}{\mu} + 1}{\cal F}\pars{\mu,\nu}
> = -\,{1 \over 2}\root{\pi \over \mu}\,{\rm erf}\pars{\nu\root{\mu}}
> \\[3mm]&
> \partiald{\bracks{\expo{\mu}{\cal F}\pars{\mu,\nu}}}{\mu}
> = -\,{1 \over 2}\,\expo{\mu}\root{\pi \over \mu}\,{\rm erf}\pars{\nu\root{\mu}}
> \\[3mm]&
> \expo{\mu}{\cal F}\pars{\mu,\nu} - {\cal F}\pars{0,\nu}
> =
> -\,{\root{\pi} \over 2}
> \int_{0}^{\mu}{\expo{\mu'}{\rm erf}\pars{\nu\root{\mu'}} \over \root{\mu'}}
> \,\dd \mu'
> \\[3mm]&
> {\cal F}\pars{\mu,\nu}
> =
> \expo{-\mu}{\cal F}\pars{0,\nu}
> -
> \expo{-\mu}\,{\root{\pi} \over 2}
> \int_{0}^{\mu}{\expo{\mu'}{\rm erf}\pars{\nu\root{\mu'}} \over \root{\mu'}}
> \,\dd \mu'
> \end{align}

$$
{\cal F}\pars{0,\nu} = \int_{0}^{\nu}{\dd x \over x^{2} - 1}\,\dd x
=
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\nu}\pars{{1 \over x - 1} - {1 \over x + 1}}\,\dd x
=
{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{1 - \mu \over \mu + 1} 
$$
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
{\cal F}\pars{\mu,\nu}
=
{1 \over 2}\,\expo{-\mu}\ln\pars{1 - \mu \over \mu + 1} 
-
\expo{-\mu}\,{\root{\pi} \over 2}
\int_{0}^{\mu}{\expo{\mu'}{\rm erf}\pars{\nu\root{\mu'}} \over \root{\mu'}}
\,\dd \mu'}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $0<c<a$, then this integral is improper at $y=c$.  So, we must write
$$
\int_0^a\frac{e^{-by^2}}{y^2-c^2}\,dy=\int_0^c\frac{e^{-by^2}}{y^2-c^2}\,dy+\int_c^a\frac{e^{-by^2}}{y^2-c^2}\,dy,
$$
and check whether these two integrals each converge.

For the first, note that for $y\in(0,c)$, $e^{-bc^2}\leq e^{-by^2}\leq 1$.  Since $y^2-c^2<0$, it follows that
$$
\frac{1}{y^2-c^2}\leq \frac{e^{-by^2}}{y^2-c^2}\leq\frac{e^{-bc^2}}{y^2-c^2}
$$
for all $y\in(0,c)$.

From here, it is not difficult to check that
$$
\lim_{M\rightarrow c^{-}}\int_0^M\frac{e^{-bc^2}}{y^2-c^2}\,dy=-\infty,
$$
so that the integral you want diverges by comparison.

So, since one of the parts of your integral diverges, the whole integral diverges.